# Google apps script - extract 1 of 4 csv files from within a zipped email attachment & paste it into google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below GAS which works well - an email is received with an attached csv file and it copies the data from the csv file into a google sheet

However, now the data to be copied is being received as a zip folder attachment to an email which contains 4 csv files. I need to copy the data from the second CSV file and paste it into the google sheet as before.

Im struggling to adapt the code to do this - can anyone please help?

```
  
  //GET MOST RECENT MESSAGE BY LABEL
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('sbh_channel');
  var threads = label.getThreads(0, 1);
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  message = message[message.length - 1];
  Logger.log("Message Found");
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
  var attachment = attachments[i];
  }
  Logger.log("Attachement Stored");

  //REMOVE LABEL
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("new_12monthOtb");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  threads[i].removeLabel(label);}
  Logger.log("Label removed");

  //FIND SPREADHSEET
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById ("1DLCn9mwhwlKD6eCDGWVA119X_CL-zPOnQbPk_ncaDtE");
  Logger.log("SS Opened");

  //FIND SHEET INSIDE SPREADHSEET
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Mews");
  Logger.log("Tab Found");

  //PARSE CSV DATA
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'), ",");
  Logger.log("CSV data loaded");
    
  //INSERT DATA AKA .getRange(row, column, lastrow based on CSV data);
  sheetName.getRange(2, 2, csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  Logger.log("Data pasted");

  //HIDE SHEET
  sheetName.hideSheet();
  Logger.log("sheet hidden");
  Logger.log("Script Complete");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve 2nd file from a ZIP file including 4 CSV files.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'), ",");
```

#### To:

```
var blobs = Utilities.unzip(attachment.setContentType(MimeType.ZIP)); // or var blobs = Utilities.unzip(attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension());
if (blobs.length <= 1) {
  throw new Error("2nd file cannot be found.");
}
var csvFileOf2ndFile = blobs[1];
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFileOf2ndFile.getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'), ",");
```

- When this modified script is run and your `attachment` is ZIP content, the ZIP data is unzipped and the 2nd file is retrieved from the unzipped 4 CSV files, and it is used as `csvData`.
- About you 2nd file, if you want to retrieve the file using a filename, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var csvFileOf2ndFile = blobs[1];
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var csvFileOf2ndFile = blobs.find(b => b.getName() == "sample.csv"); // Please set the CSV filename you want to retreive.
    ```

#### Note:

- In this modification, when your `attachment` is not valid ZIP content, this script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.
- If this modification was not useful, can you provide your sample ZIP file? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### Reference:

- [unzip(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob)

Comment: Thanks for the help - but I am getting an error with the solution. 

I think it has something to do with the charset of the second csv file because when I tested on some variants - it worked OK for the first and third csv file - but if I try to parse the second csv file get error "Exception: Could not parse text." error on line 43:
`var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFileOf2ndFile.getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'), ",");`

Is there anyway to get GAS to find out what the charset is, and input that?

Comment: @nick Thank you for replying. From your reply, I'm worried that the 2nd file might not be the CSV data or `getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1')` might be able to be used. But, unfortunately, I cannot know your zip file and CSV data. But, when I tested my script using a zip file including 4 CSV files, no error occurs. I apologize for this. For example, if the reason for your current issue is due to the character code, can you provide your sample zip file including the CSV files for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I;' love to share the zip & files but they contain some sensitive information. The code you provided defiantly works for the other 3 csv files, just not this one. the files have all come from the same app so thought they would have been in the same format - however the second file contains the most data. so its either an encoding /charset or file length issue? is there a way I can view the charset used in a file?

Comment: @nick Thank you for replying. I think that your actual data is not required to be shared. In this case, it is required to confirm the sample data for correctly replicating your current issue. But, I think that the reason that I cannot correctly imagine your actual character code is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: @nick Or, your question is to retrieve one of the CSV files from a zip file. I think that my answer can resolve it. But, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot find the actual character code of your current issue.  So, how about splitting your question between retrieving one of CSV file from a zip file and parsing the CSV data with the specific character code? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252645/discussion-between-nick-and-tanaike).

Comment: @nick Thank you for replying. When you post a new question, if you can provide a sample file of the sample texts written by the specific character code you want to use, I think that it will be useful for understanding your situation. But, if you cannot do it, please don't worry. At that time, I would like to think of another method for retrieving the character code from the data.